# Accessing .wps files in a Windows version of some OpenOffice variant

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, microsoft-works

A friend recently got a new Windows computer, and is in the process of installing apps on it.  She has a bunch of old .wps files from Microsoft Works, which did not come installed on the new machine.  It did come with a pseudo-version of MS Office, which seemed to be trialware or adware or something.  She found it annoying, so I removed it and installed OpenOffice.org.

Unfortunately, the vanilla/official/Oracle version of OOo does not support accessing .wps files.  [go-oo](http://go-oo.org) states on their home page that their variant supports this feature, however, [their download page](http://go-oo.org/download) has not worked for me during the past couple of days, perhaps as a result of their having merged into LibreOffice.

I've not found any conclusive indication of whether or not LibreOffice supports this feature; there are [vague rumblings in the ether](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/libreoffice-33#postContent-184734) to the effect that support is dubious at best.

It sounds like use of the libwps library [needs to be compiled into the OOo build](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Writer/DocumentManagement/How_can_I_open_Microsoft_Works_wordprocessor_files_(.wps)%3F) in order to make this feature available.

Does the current version of LibreOffice support accessing .wps files?  If not, is it still possible to download the most recent version of go-oo?  If not, is there some other variant available with a Windows build that can do this?

#### update

The [new features](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/new-features-and-fixes/) page for LibreOffice version 3.3.1 does list Works import capabilities.  I'm not running Windows myself, so I'll wait for my <s>guinea pig</s> friend to try this out before answering my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My trusted assistant (the friend mentioned in the question) has confirmed that LibreOffice 3.3.1 for Windows, as [advertised](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/new-features-and-fixes/), is able to open .wps files, or import them, or whatever "bring up" means in her own personal jargon vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice will open the file, with strikethrough on every word. If you remove formatting (Apple Style: far left second row of info bar) it will all be removed - and can then be saved easily, in whatever format you choose.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice on Linux definitely *does* open WPS files - just checked again to make sure for you - so I would suspect that the Windows version will be fine too.

Comment: If you've installed via your distro package manager, this could have been added by the distro maintainers.  For example, the ubuntu version of *OpenOffice.org* provides .wps access functionality.